# Calculo em Excel e PHP/SQL com resultado diferente

Tags: php, sql, microsoft-excel

Realizei o cálculo de uma coluna em minha planilha e o valor é X. Porém, quando realizo o calculo da coluna com SQL utilizando SUM, ou até mesmo em um loop com PHP, o valor é diferente.

O engraçado é que os valores entre SQL/PHP batem, já o resultado do Excel é o único diferente.

Na coluna há valores com a seguinte formatação: 8.923245614035087, e também há valores com E, alguns em branco...

Comment: isso é simples resolver, limite a quantidade de dígitos após a virgula para por exemplo 5 dígitos em ambos, que conseguirá o mesmo resultado. No php utilize numbr_format($numero,'2') e no excel tem um ícone para isso.

Comment: Acontece que eu preciso do número exato para o calculo, uma vez que o mesmo será utilizado para gráficos, etc...

Comment: Sabe informar o motivo de PHP/SQL e EXCEL interpretarem diferente?

Comment: Interpreta pelo motivo acima descrito, a quantidade de dígitos após a vírgula. Eu uso para gráficos constantemente essa função que mencionei e sempre deixo 5 caracteres, a acurácia será praticamente a mesma, exceto se aplicado para uso pluviométrico. Dados gerais. Experimente em ambos quantos dígitos será satisfatório.